# How can i retreive the user who posted the post

Tags: php, laravel, blogs

I am learning laravel by developing a small blog. I have created all the necessary relationships. But i am unable to get the name of the user who created the post originally.

i have tried

```
$post->user->name;
```

but this returns `null`, however if I do

```
$post->user->id
```

it returns the id of the user who created the post

My post model has this relationship

```
# Post.php

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}
```

My user model has this relationship

```
# User.php

public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

the results that i want is that if i write

```
$post->user->name
```

it should display the user's name

Right now im getting similar results by using this statement:

```
{{ \App\User::find($post->user_id)->name  }}
```

Comment: my relationship is a one to many i.e  One User can Post Many posts

Comment: Do you have the `name` field in your `users` table?

Comment: yes i have name field present in the user table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your relationship definition. The `Post` model should point the `User` model:

#### Post.php

```
use App\User; // <----

// ...

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}   //                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also, you shouldn't do queries directly from the frontend, instead, try [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the relationship in the back and and then return the object to the view:

#### PostController.php

```
public function show(Request $request)
{
    $post = Post::with('user')->find(1);
    //            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return view('my_view')->with('post', $post);
}
```

Then in your view you just use the object directly:

#### my_view.blade.php

```
<h1> {{ $post->user->name }} </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

This `relationship` on the `Post` model is wrong:

```php
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}
```

It should be:

```php
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

With the relationship in place `$post->user->name` in a view should work out of the box.

You don't need to *eager load* `User` if you are retrieving a single `Post`, *eager load* is able to reduce the needed queries when you get a `collection` of `posts` and the associated `users`.

If you get a *single* `Post` with eager load the `User` or without the queries are the same.

Comment: Thanks alot sir. It was a very stupid mistake. Fixing the relationships fixed the issue. However i'm still unable to understand how does the "$post->user-id" was working but "$post->user->name" was not